# Asp.net 5 Build Up Object with registered services / components

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

In asp before asp.net 5 I had all dependencies in a UnityContainer. Now one part of my api creates new EntityInstances.

Currently it looks like this

```
 public T CreateNew<T>(string id)
 {
      var entity = container.Resolve<T>(); //Creates a new instance and fills the depdencies
      entity.Id = id;
      return entity;
 }
```

Some of those EntityImplementation have references to registered Components.
With Unity there components would automatically have been injected to the ctor and annotated properties.

But now when the ApplicationStarts all that I have is the `IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices`

Is there a way to get objects build up with the servies thar are registered there?

Currently I don't want to use Unity as the ASP.net 5 ServiceProvider. Is thre a way how to do this with the classes asp 5 nativly provides ? Does anyone know which type asp uses to inject dependencies to the controllers?

Comment: Injecting services into entities is [a bad idea](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/14/injecting-services-into-entities/).

Comment: Yes your right, but this problem is of a more generic kind, and the above is only an example which demonstrated the problem in a simplified way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The solution is the [ActivatorUtilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.owin.hosting.services.activatorutilities(v=vs.111).aspx).
It provides access to similar functionality like the unityContainer does. And its DIC agnostic, so what ever DIC you configure you can use this static interface.

static The solution is to use

```
Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>
```

So my method would look like:

```
  public sealed class ServiceProviderDomainObjectFactory<T> : IDomainObjectFactory<T>
    {
        private  IServiceProvider provider;

        public void SetProvider(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        public ServiceProviderDomainObjectFactory()
        {

        }

        public T CreateNew<T>(string id)
        {
            var test = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>(id,provider);
            return (T1) test;
        }
  }
```